# og2ogr character encoding problem

Tags: ogr2ogr, utf-8, encode

When I'm dissolving a shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr "b:\out.shp" "b:\Tele.shp" -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry), nev, jar FROM Tele GROUP BY jar"
```

I got error message like:

> Warning 1: One or several characters couldn't be converted correctly from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.

I don't understand this because Tele.cpg contains "UTF-8"

When trying this:

```
ogr2ogr "b:\out.shp" "b:\Tele.shp" -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry), nev, jar FROM Tele GROUP BY jar" ENCODING=UTF-8
```

the error message is:

> Warning 1: layer names ignored in combination with -sql.
>   ERROR 1: Failed to create field name 'nev' : cannot convert to "UTF-8"

So what should I do to keep my strange Hungarian characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type `-lco` before the `ENCODING=UTF-8` part, a.k.a `-lco ENCODING=UTF-8` and it should work (it did for me and my strange Polish characters).

Comment: It creates a .cpg file along side the .shp file, and in QGIS I noticed I still have to change the encoding from 'System' to 'UTF-8' in the properties for the attribute table to display characters correctly.

Comment: I tried to apply this when creating a GeoJSON, result: `Warning 6: dataset newfile.geojson does not support layer creation option ENCODING`